# How can I forward my selected items to another page in Flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, listview

I have some datas and I can see in the homepage.
I want to see also in the another page, how can i do this?

I have card for example, and It has some datas like fav_numbers, name, last_name etc. and I want to pass these informations to another page. Then, I can see these cards (only selected) in the another page. How can i do this?

I want to pass like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {
AutoRouter.of(context).push(
PeopleRoute(
name: games[index]["name"],
surname: games[index]["surname"],
luckyNumber: games[index]["luckyNumber"]),
 );
 },
child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
 ),
```

and I can use these informations in people page like widget.name or widget.surname . But I need to a list right? Because I do not want to show just 1 card, I want to show **when user click PLUS(+) button, then I want to show cards which are selected.**

If you show simply, I can continue with using other state management ways...

Comment: Check this flutter [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data).

Comment: Can you include what is `AutoRouter` and `Card` widget?

Comment: AutoRouter is package. And card widget is card which has name surname etc informations

Comment: I need to a list actually, I need to push when I click + button, then I can show this list on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just I needed to create items in another widget, which I wanted.

Comment: Could you show your solution please?